# error while pushing using $push in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, api

My schema

```
{
     { 
       '_id': ObjectId()  #generated by MongoDB on record submission
       'name':_name, 
       'email':_email,
       'lastLogin': 
                [{'ip': _ip, '_browser': _browser}
                ]}
     }
```

I want to find a record by providing the "id" & push inside `lastLogin`

Output I need:

```
{
     { 
       '_id': ObjectId()  #generated by MongoDB on record submission
       'name':_name, 
       'email':_email,
       'lastLogin': 
                [{'ip': _ip, '_browser': _browser},
                {'ip': _ip}, '_browser': _browser}
                ]}
     }
```

My code:

```
mongo.db.users.update({ '_id': ObjectId(id) },
   { "$push": { 'lastLogin': {'ip': '12.54.231.65', 'browser': 'Apple safari'} } }
)
```

Thanks for the help.

Original Code: Flask & Mongo Db, & using postman(check link to see the image.)

```
@app.route('/api/user/update/<id>')
def update_user(id):
    #user = mongo.db.users.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)})
    _json = request.json
    _ip = _json['ip']
    _browser = _json['browser']

    [enter image description here][1]mongo.db.users.update({ '_id': ObjectId(id) },
   { "$push": { "lastLogin": { "ip" : _ip, "browser": _browser} } }
    )


    return jsonify("updated")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/59gnl.png

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Oleg SyntaxError: invalid syntax at the $push place.

Comment: Add the exact error message into the question. Clarify which language you are working in.

Comment: @Oleg I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

There were two problems:

1. I didn't add the method = ['POST']
2. $push should be "$push"